# Compiling the JVM

Tags: java, jvm

Is possible to compile the JVM to some specific ISA?

I'm trying to understand the JVM's proposal. Everything I now, that is a Virtual Machine who simulates an ISA over any ISA, thus, it is just another software running over the SO. But all the softwares must be compiled to the target ISA, to achieve the correctly instructions.

So, is JVM recompiled for every new ISA? Or it has an specific way to do that and maintain the portability?

Comment: The JVM is just a program like any other. It is compiled into machine code for the respective architecture.

Comment: The JVM, in turn, runs the Java bytecode on any system with the JVM installed.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than a single JVM, hence, there is no simple answer to questions about “the” JVM.

In principle, it is possible to implement a JVM in a portable programming language featuring a simple interpreter for byte code execution only. In that case, it would be possible to support all architectures supported by the language used for implementing the JVM. If that language requires compiling the source code for a particular architecture (which is true for the languages typically used for such a task), then, the JVM has to be recompiled for each supported ISA. Usually, you also need to recompile it for each supported operation system, even for the same ISA.

But in practice, JVMs feature just-in-time compilation to native code, as well as features needing interaction with the underlying architecture beyond the standard features of the programming language used for the implementation (like C or C++). So, to support a new architecture, it is not enough to recompile the JVM source code, it is also needed to implement a new JIT compiler for a new ISA and to provide specialized implementation of some low level components. This applies to the widely used HotSpot JVM, which is part of the JDKs and JREs you can download from [Oracle’s website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). You may notice, that you have to pick the right version for your system (if supported).

Another possible strategy is to implement a JVM in Java itself. To be able to run it on a particular platform, at least some parts of it have to get compiled to native code ahead-of-time, which requires a suitable AOT compiler. If the particular project features a compilation to native code anyway (as part of the JIT compiler), utilizing it to implement an AOT compiler, is not too far-fetched. Such a project would be independent from another language’s platform support, but of course, it still requires implementing and maintaining specific code to support a particular architecture. This applies to the Substrate JVM, part of [the GraalVM project](https://www.graalvm.org/).